# why webpack multiple-entry-points then one file modified compile all

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have used the webpack with  multiple-entry-points, for instance the entries are `index1.js` and `index2.js`, and the outputs are `bundle1.js` and `bundle2.js`, once I modify `index1.js`, it seems that the two bundles will be packed, but in fact only `bundle1.js` needs to be packed again.

How I can realize my goal? I use `webpack-dev-server` as a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I use Uglify Plugin in my dev environment, which causes the result

Answer (score 0):

One of the goals of webpack-dev-server is to only reload the modules that changed. In the scenario you describe, why do you want bundle2.js to be rebuilt? It seems it would just result in the same file that already exists.

This is also the behavior of webpack's `--watch` option: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/